# Align the text as center in flex layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If we want to align the text as center or end of the div, we need to show the ellipsis, If text length was overflowed the div width.

Here below sample was work fine.

My expectation is: If we add the item class to the parent div it will be worked as the same like which was applied in the span.

**Working Example:** https://codepen.io/Muthupandi07/pen/oRVwqV

Thanks in advance.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="controls">
<select id="justifyMe">
  <option value="flex-start">flex-start</option>
  <option value="flex-end">flex-end</option>
  <option value="center">center</option>
</select>    
</div>

<div class="container" id="container">
  <span class="item">How to center an item using flexbox</span>      
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font: 1em Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

* {box-sizing: border-box;}

p {
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

.container {  
  border: 5px solid rgb(111,41,97);
  border-radius: .5em;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
}

.item {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: pre;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.controls {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: .5em;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  margin: 0 0 2em 0
}

.controls select {
  font-size: .9em;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var justify = document.getElementById("justifyMe");
justifyMe.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
  document.getElementById("container").style.justifyContent = evt.target.value;
});
```

Comment: Add width:150px; to span.item for view center and flex-end

Comment: @HirenVaghasiya, If we add width 150 for span, in flex-end mode it will hide the some text

Comment: but you are already using text-overflow: ellipsis; so by default it will not displaying all text

Comment: @Hiren, Yes it was not displaying all text, but instead of, it will show the ellipsis. If we add as per your concerns, width as 150 for span, the ellipsis also not shown.

Comment: I added answer with applying width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can apply max-width:90%; to span.item for viewing center and flex-end

```js
var justify = document.getElementById("justifyMe");
justifyMe.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
  document.getElementById("container").style.justifyContent = evt.target.value;
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font: 1em Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

* {box-sizing: border-box;}

p {
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

.container {  
  border: 5px solid rgb(111,41,97);
  border-radius: .5em;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
}

.item {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: pre;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width:90%;
}

.controls {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: .5em;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  margin: 0 0 2em 0
}

.controls select {
  font-size: .9em;
}
```

```html
<div class="controls">
<select id="justifyMe">
  <option value="flex-start">flex-start</option>
  <option value="flex-end">flex-end</option>
  <option value="center">center</option>
</select>

</div>

<div class="container" id="container">
  <span class="item">How to center an item using flexbox</span>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @hiren, But if I change the container width from 200px to 400px. it will not work as expected.

Comment: Even if we want to change the container width, it will need to work as the same behavior. The inner text will be work(with an ellipsis or without ellipsis) based on the container width

Comment: Hi @Hiren, But if we choose a center mode, after changing the container width as 400px, it will not at the center of the div.

Comment: @Pandi yes i have checked it so it's not center for more than 200px width using %

Comment: Okay @hiren, But I want a generic solution for this.

Comment: Is there any other possible to remove the Item class from span and apply any style for the container?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  <div class="parent">
>  <span class="child"> center me </span>
>  <div>
> .parent {
>  display: flex;
>  }
>
> .child {
>  margin: auto;
>   }
> ```

Comment: It will center the whole div. But my requirement is center the inner span element text. If text length was more than div's width, the text needs to be shown as in ellipsis format.